# Best way to attach a wooden frame to the pole?

Tags: outdoor, door-frame, support, pole

[image]
 Same pole on each side. Wanting to put 2 doors, each 8ft h x 5ft w, leading to carport need to control dust, I have the door construction idea based on how I am able to make a frame. Thinking drill holes and attach with bolts, can't weld, don't want to damage poles, deforming shape, but holes are acceptable if only option. 
Any suggestions appreciated,  planning to use foam padding against the rock wall so mainly just don't want the frame to be able to rotate when opening and closing the doors.  Thank you.

First time asking please excuse any errors in terminology.

Comment: You might be able to use something like this (https://www.lowes.com/pd/wap-oz-standard-hot-dipped-galvanized-steel-fence-mounting-bracket/1000440261) to avoid damaging the pole with holes. If you could share more details of your door design, it would be helpful.

Comment: I was thinking about u bolt brackets , @Gregory nickoloff , make that an answer but explain about the U bolt brackets as link only answers are frowned on, if the link breaks no one has a clue what you were thinking, it’s a good idea even in comments.

Comment: @EdBeal - You're right about the permanence of the link. My bad. My comment was really intended to be more asking for clarification than answering the question. U-brackets (or the brackets in the link) might be a poor choice and not worthy of an answer if the doors turn out to be something other than what I imagine...Kind of holding off on an "answer" without knowing more about the doors.

Comment: make sure to attach the enclosure to the ceiling joists so that the enlosure does not rotate around the post